# How to maximise nested containers?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

The problem is the following:

> Given N containers with different sizes between 1 and N (2 <= N <= 10^5), each of them placed in a line, determine how many places can be freed if one container can be placed in another only if its size is less that the others size and they don't have any other containers between them. Multiple placings can be made, so if there are containers placed in each other, they can be placed in another container (if the bottom container size is less than the others size), a container can be placed in another group of container (if its size is less than the top container size), and a group of containers can be placed in another group of containers with similar rules.
>   Example: if N = 8 and the containers are placed in the following order: 1 8 2 4 3 6 7 5, then 7 places can be freed; we place 3 in 4, then 2 in 3, 6 in 7, 5 in 6, 4 in 5, 7 in 8, and 1 in 2. This way all the containers can be packed in a single group.

My idea of solving this problem is the following: calculate the minimum difference between all the neighbour containers sizes, then find the first pair where this minimum appears and make a placement. Then repeat the whole process again until no placements can be made. Then calculate the freed places.
This can be done trivially in quadratic time, but that is too slow. The other thing that bothers me that this method may not lead to the optimal solution.

**Edit** for clarification: I don't want to have my job done by others, I posted this because I got stuck solving the problem, and needed some help to know if my approach is correct or how can I make optimizations. Also the solution is not language specific, so I think the implementation of a pseudocode algorithm is trivial. Thanks is advance!

Comment: Please do not describe your code - show it.

Comment: A "fancy data structure" is too broad as a question. So is "better algorithm". Also, please try to avoid the impression that you just want an answer to a homework assignment.

Comment: If you need just the algorithm to start, it may be better to drop any language tag. It will attract unnessary downvotes from people thinking you want to get your homework done by them

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Interesting idea. Never considered restricting a question to only those people who work on the language-agnostic meta level. But makes some sense. Better chances for an answer however lie in asking a language-focused question (with the appropriate amount of demonstrated own effort in coding and research).

Comment: What is the reason for a better algorithm? Have you met with timing restrictions? Or to ask differently: What are the real-time constraints? How much did you violate them?

Comment: Indeed, there are timing restrictions: my program (coded in C++) has to finish in 200 ms. For large N, a quadratic solution doesn't have a chance. Also, take a look at my edit in the original post.

Comment: Using a priority queue reduces time to linearithmic.

Comment: @Yunnosch almost all the questions I've been interested in on SO just asked for a "better algorithm." And if they didn't, I became interested because one or more better algorithms were offered.

Comment: We can regard a stack of containers as an interval of sizes, from the smallest to the largest; two adjacent container stacks can be combined iff these intervals do not intersect.  I've thought of a necessary condition for a "perfect" solution (one that combines all the containers): In each group of 3 adjacent containers (x, y, z), in a perfect solution we must *first* combine either a stack containing x with a stack containing y, or a stack containing y with a stack containing z.  Whenever the interval [x, y] contains z, it must be that y and z are combined first.

Comment: ... (And similarly if [y, z] contains x, then it must be that x and y are combined first.)  Note that when (x, y, z) are in order or reverse order, we can't conclude anything directly.  If you create a graph with a vertex for each adjacent pair of containers, and an edge whenever the above logic gives us a precedence relationship between two combine operations, then a perfect solution corresponds to some topological ordering of the graph.  But it's not necessarily the case that any topological ordering of vertices gives a perfect solution, since there could be other constraints to fulfil.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an `O(n log n)`-time algorithm.

Our strategy is to identify the longest prefix of containers that can be packed into one group and recurse on the rest. To see why this is optimal, first consider that removing containers from an instance never increases the minimum number of groups that can remain, since given a sequence of moves we can just delete the ones involving the missing containers. Our greedy strategy leaves the minimal suffix, so it's optimal by strong induction.

To find the longest prefix, we use [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) with the test below. Overall, each search will end up costing `O(p log p)` time where `p` is the length of the longest prefix. Summed over all of the prefixes, the total is `O(n log n)`.

Given containers numbered `1...n`, there exists a linear-time algorithm due to Bose, Buss, and Lubiw (Pattern matching for permutations, from 1998) to test whether it can be packed into one group. (As a side note, they named these permutations [*separable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_permutation).) It's a shift-reduce algorithm that keeps a stack of intervals. To shift a container `k`, push the interval `[k, k+1)` onto the stack. Whenever the top two elements of the stack are `[a, b), [b, c)` or `[b, c), [a, b)` for some `a, b, c`, pop them and push `[a, c)`. At the end, the stack has exactly one element if and only if the containers can be packed into one group.

Now, you may have noticed that, in general, prefixes of the input are *not* numbered `1...n`. The easy way out is to sort and number the prefix under test each time, which makes the cost of the test `O(p log p)` and leads to an `O(n log^2 n)`-time algorithm. Perhaps this is good enough. If not, observe that `O(p log p)` is enough time to sort the prefixes in the first phase of exponential search (because the costs increase exponentially). Thereafter, we have some upper bound `u` for which `u/2 ≤ p < u`, and we have consecutive indexes for the first `u` containers. In `O(p)` time, then, we can compute new indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with so far are some ideas maybe someone can develop more fully (or point to a flaw).

Iterate again from left to right, and for each element at index `r`, look backwards to seek the longest sequence, `(l, r)`, we can make, noting the new ranges we construct on the way (the low and high bounds do not necessarily correspond with the elements at indexes `l` and `r`). We extend a range, provided the element is either greater than the high bound or lower than the low bound.

Notice that the low and high bounds are monotonically decreasing and increasing, respectively, as each sequence is extended backwards (to the left), which means they can be sought with binary search if need be.

```
i: 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
   1   8   2   4   3   6   7   5

l is displayed as (index, range)
index r
  0     -> [(0, (0,0))]
  1     -> [(0, (1,8))]
  2     ->
    [(1, (2,8)), (0, (1,8))]
  3     ->
    [(2, (2,4)), (1, (2,8)),
     ... repeated]
  4     ->
    [(3, (3,4)), (2, (2,4)),
     ... repeated]
  5     ->
    (4, (3,6)) cannot extend back
    to element 4 at index 3, but
    element 6 can join earlier,
    reachable ranges.
     [(4, (3,6)), (3, (3,6)),
      (2, (2,6)), (1, (2,8)),
      ... repeated]
  6     ->
    [(5, (6,7)), (4, (3,7)),
     (3, (3,7)), (2, (2,7)),
     (1, (2,8)) ... repeated]
  7     ->
    [(6, (5,7)), (5, (5,7)),
     (3, (3,7)) ... repeated)
```

We can see that during the backwards search, once we can insert an element into a previously seen interval associated with a left array index, we can just lookup the best associated solution that extends it leftward; otherwise, we update with new intervals not previously seen for that index.

This looks like `O(n^2)` since each subarray potentially points to an associated element range. But any one left array index that points to a particular range has only one best sequence extending leftward, regardless of how many subarrays it belongs to. (We see 13 unique `(left, (low,high))`s in the example, yet `(n-1)*n/2 = 28`). My hope is this points to some optimisation.